# Insert to the right of cursor

Tags: cursor, insert

**Q:** What is the simplest way to insert text *without moving the cursor*?

Is there a command, say `insert-right-of-point`, that does just that already? I did not find one and gave up after several `C-h a`.

My best solution at the moment is to define the command with some `(save-excursion (apply 'insert args))` but there are probably better ways (better = faster, or more robust, or more elegant, or ... Have your pick).

**PS.** For people who ask *"what do you need that for?!"*: I have a program that insert things in a buffer but the natural way of computing what to insert produces several bits of text in succession, and it produces the last bits first.

Comment: Seems like `(save-excursion (insert "text"))` is pretty simple and to the point.